# Pandas multiply selected columns by previous column

Tags: python, pandas

Assume I have a 3 x 9 Dataframe with index from 0 - 2 and columns from 0 - 8

```
nums = np.arange(1, 28)
arr = np.array(nums)
arr = arr.reshape((3, 9))
df = pd.DataFrame(arr)
```

I want to multiply selected columns (example [2, 5, 7]) by the columns behind them (example [1, 4, 6])
My obstacle is getting the correct index of the previous column to match with the column I want to multiply

Issue:

```
df[[2, 5, 7]] = df[[2, 5, 7]].multiply(___, axis="index") # in this case I want the blank to be df[[1, 4, 6]], but how to get these indexes for the general case when selected columns vary?
```

Comment: The tool you're looking for is called [shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's try working with the numpy array:

```
cols = np.array([2,5,7])

df[cols] *= df[cols-1].values
```

Output:

```
    0   1    2   3   4    5   6    7   8
0   1   2    6   4   5   30   7   56   9
1  10  11  132  13  14  210  16  272  18
2  19  20  420  22  23  552  25  650  27
```

Or you can use:

```
df.update(df[cols]*df.shift(-1, axis=1))
```

which gives:

```
    0   1      2   3   4      5   6      7   8
0   1   2   12.0   4   5   42.0   7   72.0   9
1  10  11  156.0  13  14  240.0  16  306.0  18
2  19  20  462.0  22  23  600.0  25  702.0  27
```